# What is the meaning of こう見えて in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> こう見えてなかなかの策士

I get the なかなかの策士 part, but what does the first part of the sentence mean?

Comment: ...did you try looking up こう見えて on your own? if you did, was the result confusing?

Comment: or try looking up こう見えて**も**

Comment: Do こう見えて and こう見えても share the same meaning?

Comment: @Ushiromiya Yes, they basically have the same meaning..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> こう見えて（も）、～～。

is used to say "Despite one's appearance", "Contrary to how one looks", "Even though one may look otherwise".

> こう見えてなかなかの策士。
>   Contrary to how he looks, / He may not look like one, but he is quite a schemer.

こう見えて（も） literally means "Even though (one) looks/appears this way". こう refers to how one looks/appears, and the phrase is used to say that it (= how one looks / one's appearance) doesn't match what one actually is.

Answer (score 4):

"It may look like that, but~"
"I know it looks like that, but~"
"It seems that way, but~"

「こう見えて」は「見た目は～しそうに見えない」という意味です。

例えば

> 彼女はこう見えて、女性です。
>
> 彼はこう見えて、弁護士です。
>
> 彼はこう見えて、ヘビースモーカーです。
>
> 私、こう見えても大食いなんです。
> "I know it looks that way, but I'm actually a big eater."

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it definitely helps! :) I can't seem to translate my sentence using your translations though, because it could only make sense for me if it was "He may not look like one, but he is a schemer."

Comment: Maybe "It doesn't seem to be the case, but he is quite a schemer" would work?

Comment: 他のサイトからの転載でしたら、リンクを貼るなどして出典を明示して、blockquote に入れるなどしてどこが引用箇所かわかるようにしてください。。。　https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/30138/