# What does これでも mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

Context is:
見りゃわかんだろ
これでも必死で走って来たんだよ!

Translation I have: Can't you tell?! We ran our asses off here!

How does これでも come into play?
Internet says it means "even though things may appear this way" but that cannot be the case because of the 見りゃわかんだろ.
I was thinking これ refers to the speaker, but でも cannot be "as well", since **they** were the ones running, not the listeners. Please help me understand.

Context:

[image: comic page 1]

[image: comic page 2]

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61947/9831 ... and maybe this one too? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63059/9831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

これでも (literally "even with this" or "in spite of this") in this context means "in spite of the (bad) result (of being late)" or "although you may be thinking I'm lazy". これ in これでも often refers to the speaker's appearance, but it can vaguely refer to any "bad situation" at hand.

Answer (score -2):

First part can be rephrased less casually, and should make it easier for you to understand the sentence:

見れば分からないだろう
You cannot understand by just looking [at how I look right now]

これでも
Even so,

必死で走ってきた
I [actually] ran my ass off here!

Comment: I thought わかん is short for 分かるの and what I found was 見ればわかる means it's obvious just by looking at it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ZsófiaSzentkirályi No, you're correct. わかん＝わかるの in this case. Also, 必死 doesn't mean "actually".